# MS-SQL Type Casting Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting

I had a quick question regarding how T-SQL (MS-SQL) handles data type casts. I have these two queries that return the respective values noted below but I'm wondering why the 2nd one displays this way. Is the full value actually being captured? The data type of the column in question is a float. Just need these to be equal to compare using an IF statement.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT SUM ([CS_EQ_SHPD]) as CS_EQ_SHPD
FROM  [Supplies_DB].DBO.[ITEM] 
LEFT JOIN [Supplies_DB].DBO.[BU] 
ON BU_# = Business_Unit
WHERE FISC_WEEK = '49' AND FY17_Market = 'Southeast'
```

**Return Value:** 2953432.88

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT CAST(SUM ([CS_EQ_SHPD]) AS NVARCHAR(50)) as CS_EQ_SHPD
FROM  [Supplies_DB].DBO.[ITEM] 
LEFT JOIN [Supplies_DB].DBO.[BU] 
ON BU_# = Business_Unit
WHERE FISC_WEEK = '49' AND FY17_Market = 'Southeast'
```

**Return Value:** 2.95343e+006

Comment: Meaning you don't want the notation, but still want the value as a nvarchar(50) but looks like 2953432.88  ?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm more curious as to how this works in the background. Like why does it do that "e+" starting with the last non-decimal digit when 50 characters is more than enough to hold the whole float value?

Comment: What is @@version?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2016 19:14:09   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll start seeing the notation a 1MM.  (I'll do a little reasearch just because I'm now interested)

However, to correct your issue, you may have to use Format().  This would allow for a variable number of decimal places.  Converting to other numeric forces the number of decimals displayed.

Format() has some nice features, but it is not known for its performance

**Example**

```
Declare @V float = 2953432.88

Select AsFloat  = @V
      ,AsFormat = format(@V,'#.#########') -- Is a string but you can cast as nvarchar(50)
```

**Returns**

```
AsFloat     AsFormat
2953432.88  2953432.88
```

Now if the float value was only 1 decimal

```
AsFloat     AsFormat
2953432.8   2953432.8
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to cast( col as money)

Comment: If the float value was 2953432.8, the casted money would show 2953432.80  ... notice the last decimal

Comment: Yeah, I could format it but I have hundreds of these queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `FORMAT(Value, 'F2')` where 2 is scale

Answer (score 0):

To convert it also works to use STR.  It is interesting to know why it switches over to scientific notation, I am not sure why.

```
select LTRIM(STR(2953432.88,50,2))
```